GitHub Actions Workflow Fails with botocore.exceptions.ClientError (DynamoDB Local)
I tried running my pytest tests multiple ways on GitHub workflows, however, they all pretty much got errors from aws boto. The errors I got included
botocore.exceptions.ClientError: An error occurred (UnrecognizedClientException) when calling the CreateTable operation: The security token included in the request is invalid.

or
botocore.exceptions.NoRegionError: You must specify a region.

This is the simplest that I could create the workflow so far and I am currently getting
botocore.exceptions.ClientError: An error occurred (UnrecognizedClientException) when calling the CreateTable operation: The security token included in the request is invalid.

name: Automated Tests
permissions: read-all

on:
  workflow_dispatch:
  push:
    branches:
      - main
      - develop
  pull_request:
    branches:
      - main
      - develop
      - "*"

jobs:
  pytest-tests:
    name: Run Pytest Tests
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    env:
      ENV: "local"
      REDIS_HOST: "127.0.0.1"
      REDIS_PORT: "6379"
      REDIS_SSL_ENABLED: "False"
      AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID: "dummy"
      AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY: "dummy"
      AWS_DEFAULT_REGION: "us-west-2"
      AWS_REGION: "us-west-2"
      DYNAMO_ENDPOINT: "http://localhost:8001"

    services:
      dynamodb:
        image: amazon/dynamodb-local
        ports:
          - 8001:8000   # my API runs on port 8000 so DynamoDB runs on 8001

    steps:
      - name: Checkout
        uses: actions/checkout@v4

      - name: Set up Python
        uses: actions/setup-python@v5
        with:
          python-version: "3.x"

      - name: Install Poetry
        run: pip install poetry

      - name: Install dependencies with Poetry
        run: poetry install --no-root

      - name: Run Tests with Pytest
        run: poetry run pytest -k test_update_customer

Am I writing the workflow correctly? How can I fix the local DynamoDB so that it runs on CI and the pytests successfully run?

Your boto3 code is failing but you don't share it? Please share the relevant code.

I don't have boto3 in my workflow. are you talking about in my python code?

Yes, that's where your exception comes from
